Installing SSL + HTTPS using a reverse proxy like caddy on Android to enable secure connections for my server Emby
I want to install a reverse proxy useful because I want to put online my emby server on top of Android 14 using https on port 8920.
I have fixed the 443 error in this way :
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip $(which caddy)

solution taken from here :
https://serverfault.com/questions/807883/caddy-listen-tcp-443-bind-permission-denied
and I removed the parameter “–disable-redirects” from the Caddyfile.
now I run caddy with this command :
/data $ sudo caddy run -c /data/Caddyfile

the situation seems to be better,but caddy seems to does still run for some reason,but I don’t understand why :
https://ibb.co/r6jw9Ss
https://ibb.co/LrmDBy1
I don’t see errors,it should work,but when I open my website,at address :
https://ziomario.ns0.it:8920
it says : unable to connect. why ?
In the emby control panel I see :
Lan Access = http://192.168.1.7:8096 (and it works)
Wan Access = https://ziomario.ns0.it:8920 (and it does not work)

In Network settings I chosen :
LAN networks = empty
local IP address = empty

http local port = 8096
https local port = 8920

http public port = 8096
https public port = 8920

external domain = ziomario.ns0.it
secure connection mode = managed by the reverse proxy.

On my router I have opened ports : 8096,8920,443,80 in TCP and UDP mode…
If you want to read the full story,I've opened a thread here :
https://caddy.community/t/installing-ssl-https-using-a-reverse-proxy-like-caddy-on-android/25182
But it seems to be hard to be able to accomplish this task,so I took the decision to ask here,too,because I know that this place is full of qualified experts in every tech field.
PS : actually this is my Caddyfile :
nano /data/Caddyfile :

ziomario.ns0.it {
               encode
               reverse_proxy 192.168.1.7:8096
}


Please don't link external images. And your screenshot are if such a low quality and are truncated so that they are more or less unreadable and thus useless. Android has a built in screen shit functionality. BTW the photos show a computer monitor. What type of device do you use? Phone, tablet, virtual machine/emulator on a PC or a something like Android x86? Your post again misses details on your network and how you are online because if a server should be accessible from the Internet and you use a common WiFi router then you have to manually forward the port from the router to the LAN device.

As your server works in your LAN I don't think this is an Android problem but a network/router configuration problem. It is also not clear if you have a public IPv4 address. Check your Internet provider if you can run a server at all on IPv4 (based on the IP you seem to be a Telecom Italia customer).

I'm not using any emulator,but Android AOSP 14 (arm64 bit) by KostaKang,where I have installed termux and then Caddy. It is connected to the Internet through the ethernet cable. On my router I have opened ports : 8096,8920,443,80 in TCP and UDP mode. I'm using DHCP because my internal IP numbers changes from time to time.

By opened ports I assume you mean that you have configured a port forwarding from the router to the Android device. The part about DHCP I don't understand. That your public Internet IP changes has nothing to to with DHCP you use in your LAN. The Internet network ends in your router and any change of he public IP does not affect your LAN if you use Ipv4 only.

ok. Now you have a more clear idea about why I can't connect to my emby server using ziomario.ns0.it:8920 ? You say that the images that I have attached are not readable,but its false. They haven't the best quality,but if you zoom them a little bit,you will see clearly the caddy messages.

The precise error that I get right now is :
ERROR : http log error dial tcp 192.168.1.6:8096: connect : connection refused. request remote ip 83.147.52.49 remote port 45394 client IP = 83.147.52.49 proto HTTP/1.1 method GET host ziomario.ns0.it url gitlab-ci.yml headers user-agent go-http-client/1.1 accept encoding gzip tls resumed false version 772 cipher_suite 4867 proto server name ziomario.ns0.it duration 0.0015 status 502 err_id 36k92p912 err_trace reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy go:1269)

Also posted on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/q/1163891/252799

Just FYI, the links to ibb.co are dead.
